# Running a batch file in a given directory using VBA

Tags: windows, vba, batch-file, cmd

When I go to my batch file's location and open it, the batch file works. My batch file is simply:

```
cd .\data
dir/b/o:n > names.txt
```

As you can see, I'm in my current directory and moving down to the sub directory "data" and coping all the names and creating a file called `names.txt`.

When I say

```
shell "location of file"
```

it opens the batch file, but the directory that is defaulted to is `C:\my documents`, so my commands won't work because it cannot find the sub directory.  I want this to be a dynamic batch file, and therefore i need to write something in VBA that will open the batch file under its current directory or something to this effect.

How do I do this?

Comment: For the sake of readability, please put some effort into correctly formatting and spelling your questions. I fixed it for you this time. Note that code can be `formatted as code` using the `{}` button.

Answer (score 8):

The following should give you the effect you seek.

My test code is:

```
Option Explicit
Sub TryShell()

  Dim PathCrnt As String

  PathCrnt = ActiveWorkbook.Path
  Call Shell(PathCrnt & "\TryShell.bat " & PathCrnt)

End Sub
```

My test batch file is named TryShell.bat and contains:

```
cd %1
dir *.* >TryShell.txt
```

I have placed my batch file in the same folder as the workbook containing my macro.

The statement `PathCrnt = ActiveWorkbook.Path` sets PathCrnt to the name of the directory containing the active workbook.  You can set PathCrnt to whatever directory you require.

When I call `Shell`, I have added `PathCrnt` as a parameter.

In my batch file, I set the current directory to `%1` which is the first parameter.

The `dir` command works as I wish because the current directory is my directory and not the system default directory.

Hope this is clear.

Comment: still same issue. I think what would be easier if someone knows a command in DOS that would call the current location of the file (where ever it is), store that location as a variable, then change directory with the variable name {cd variable_name}. this would get the correct location and then i could run my batch file.

Comment: I do not understand "still same issue."  If the macro knows the location of the batch file, it can call the batch file correctly and can pass the location as a parameter.  I have used `ActiveWorkbook.Path` as my test folder because that was convenient for me but you could change it to something else.  If the macro does not know the location of the batch file how can there be a DOS command that will find it.

Comment: Has something changed which I am overlooking or have you yet to add the complete details.

Comment: Sorry Toney, been slow on the response.  Ive rephrased the question and added everything i can to make this detailed. Check this link. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9442467/calling-batch-file-in-vba-not-working-properly]

Comment: Also your Activeworkbook.path was a much simpler way of doing what i had done.  thanks for that tip!

Comment: I have responsed to the new question.  I suspect you will have the moderators on to you.  They do not like a trail of half answered questions.  You should have updated this one not started another.

Answer (score 2):

C:\My Documents is probably the directory where your speadsheet is located. If you add

```
ChDir "C:\TheFolderWhereYourBatchIs"
```

before launching your Shell command and that should work...

Alternatively, you could change your batch file to use an absolute directory instead of a relative one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9442467/calling-batch-file-in-vba-not-working-properly], this is a better description of the problem.  thanks for the response though.