# calling Batch file in VBA not working properly

Tags: vba, command-line, batch-file, dos

I'm trying to create a program that can be used by other people. Currently, my files are in the directory `C:\Documents and Settings\jpmccros\Desktop\test`

This directory contains my `macro.xlsm`, `names.bat`, and another sub-directory called `Data`.

The batch file `names.bat` does the following:

```
cd data

dir/b/o:n > names.txt
```

This does exactly what I want it to do. When I open the batch file (which is in the directory `C:\Documents and Settings\jpmccros\Desktop\test\`, the MS DOS Command Prompts starts in `C:\Documents and Settings\jpmccros\Desktop\test\` then runs my commands and makes my file `names.txt`, and puts it exactly where I want it.

When I open up `macro.xlsm` and run the macro1, it calls the batch file to open.

This is my macro command:

```
Dim names_txt, names_bat, full_name, filename, folder As String
Dim position As Integer
Dim pathcrnt As String
full_name = ThisWorkbook.FullName
filename = ThisWorkbook.Name
position = InStr(1, full_name, filename, 1)
position = position - 1
folder = Left(full_name, position)

names_bat = folder & "names.bat"

Shell names_bat, vbMaximizedFocus
```

Now here is my problem: The macro actually opens the batch file, or at least it opens the MS DOS Command Prompt. However, when it opens the batch file, the initial directory is:

`C:\Documents and settings\jpmccros\My Documents`

I need this batch file and macro to be dynamic, therefore I need the batch file to open up its displaying directory. What's going on with this?  Is there a command I can write on my batch file?  Is it something in VBA?

Comment: So if you try `debug.print ThisWorkbook.FullName` in your code you do get "C:\Documents and Settings\jpmccros\Desktop\test\macro.xlsm" in the Immediate window , ie your code is running in the correct workbook saved to the right path?

Comment: I do not see what this adds to the previous version of your question.  I showed you how to pass `C:\Documents and Settings\jpmccros\Desktop\test\data`, or whatever folder you want, as a parameter to the batch file and how to use that parameter in a `cd` command to switch to the desired directory.  You do not explain why my solution does not meet your need.  Have you tried it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running a batch file in a given directory using VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9403341/running-a-batch-file-in-a-given-directory-using-vba)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method of accessing the batch file using `activeworkbook.path` works. The VBA code finds it, relative to its current location, and opens it.

However, the issue I was having was once VBA opens the batch file, the command prompt starts in the directory `C:\Documents and Settings\jpmccros\My Documents\` every time.

Your method does not bypass this issue. I did create a solution (and used your `activeworkbook.path` idea too). Instead of calling my batch file, I simply create one in VBA and print out a line `cd var_activeworkbook.path & "\data"`.  This way, I was able to have VBA search for the current directory and save it as a variable.

Check it out:

```
Dim pathcrnt As String, batch_file As Integer

pathcrnt = ActiveWorkbook.Path
batch_file = FreeFile()
Open pathcrnt & "names.bat" For Output As #batch_file
Print #batch_file, "cd " & pathcrnt & "\data"
Print #batch_file, "dir/b/o:n > names.txt"
Print #batch_file, "pause"
Close #batch_file

Shell pathcrnt & "names.bat", vbMaximizedFocus
```